# CPython: Understanding the difference between tp_dealloc and tp_finalize

Tags: python

After reading the documentation for both [tp_dealloc](https://docs.python.org/3.11/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_dealloc) and [tp_finalize](https://docs.python.org/3.11/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_finalize), and the finalization and deallocation [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.11/extending/newtypes.html#finalization-and-de-allocation), it's still not clear to me what to move to finalize and what to keep in dealloc. The [PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0442/) talks about implementation, and less about how to use the finalizers..

What I understood: the actual object freeing must be kept in dealloc (and therefore dealloc is a required method), the finalizer will only be called once, and there is a suggestion to move "Any call to a non-trivial object or API" to finalize. But what is non-trivial here?

- is calling C functions (that don't call back into Python) trivial?
- is calling any CPython function non-trivial?
- and is it safe to change the object state in the finalizer to an invalid state (violating whatever properties the object is expected to maintain during normal life), i.e. is the finalizer guaranteed to be followed by a dealloc?

On a more practical basis, summing all the above: let's consider a simple type that has an attribute that (always) points to a Python object. When tearing down, should the DECREF for that attribute be done in dealloc, or in finalize?

Comment: Your "tutorial" link doesn't go to a tutorial.

Comment: Oops, fixed, thanks.